# Rotation of Text in a layout to be dependent on arbitrary Map

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, cartography, dynamic-text

I have a Print composer with two map windows (*MainMap* and *InsertMap*).  I also have a bit of text which I want to rotate on the Composer and it to be dependent upon the rotation of *MainMap* what ever value it may take.

I believe I should be able to use rotation.  The question is how do I go about exposing the

```
@map_rotation
```

Variable associated with *MainMap* and using it in an expression associated with the text element in the composer and applying it to the rotation of the text element.

I am using QGIS 2.14.6 on a windows 7 box.

The use case is I am using a font symbol for my north arrow ('H' Esri North if you are interested...)

Comment: I just discovered that map_rotation (under map settings in print composer) doesn't update when the map rotation is changed under main properties.